# Address of a simple int value

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to find the address location in C of a specific variable now I try to write a code  which is this :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int g = 3;
        printf("%p %d %u ",&g,&g,&g);
        return 0;
}
```

now I am confused that why is GCC compiler is giving me warning using these :

Warnings are

```
warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'int *'
warning: format '%u' expects type 'unsigned int', but argument 4 has type 'int *'
```

Also the answers are quite amazing

```
0xbfa5953c -1079667396 3215299900
```

Now my question is which would I accept as a location to my number

Comment: Why would you want the address location? Oh, and the %p is the right one.

Comment: Thanks all of you but still i want to know why Gcc compiler is giving these warnings if i am using "%u".

Comment: It gives the warning as the flag, whether it be "%p" or "%u" implies a type. If the types do not match it will give a warning.

Comment: But in turbo c it does not gives any warning

Comment: printf uses a C feature called variadic functions, where you lose all type information. Thus a regular C compiler would not be able to detect a type error in printf. Luckily, gcc has a wonderful extension to warn you of type errors in printf.

Comment: @surbhi: The warning is the compiler telling you "look, this doesn't look like an integer to me, but I can still do what you ask and you are the boss" for your convenience. But that's just being nice; noone promised that there would be such warnings.

Comment: -Wformat in http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options

Comment: Thanks to clear my doubts everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `&g` evaluates to the same value (bitwise) in every case. It's just a matter of how those bits should be *interpreted*.

So it turns out that 0xbfa5953c (hex) == 3215299900 (dec), which is hardly surprising. The negative value is meaningless because a memory address is not a *signed* integer.

Answer (score 0):

1st one is correct location - the other if printed as unsigned hex will give you the same value too.

Note this is not the exact (or even close) location in physical memory - because almost all modern OS's use virtual addressing now.

Comment: What would be an modern OS that doesn't?

Comment: AdrianMadeUp OS doesn't --) cant be sure you know every OS in existence.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use C99, you could use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    int g = 3;
    printf("%p %" PRIdPTR " %" PRIuPTR "\n", &g, (intptr_t)&g, (uintptr_t)&g);
    return 0;
}
```

All the numbers are equivalent in the sense that they represent the same bit pattern as the address.  Hex tends to be the preferred notation for addresses, but octal (not shown) has a long history too (but requires even more digits than decimal).